# gorm many2many relationships not working, can't preload field

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm building an api to learn more from Go and I'm having a problem with the many to many relationship between 2 entities.

I have 2 models

```
type Patient struct {
    ID            uint            `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name          string          `json: "name"`
    Surname       string          `json: "surname"`
    Cellphone     int             `json: "cellphone"`
    Email         string          `json: "email"`
    Professionals []*Professional `json: "professionals" gorm:"many2many:professional_patient"`
}
```

and

```
type Professional struct {
    ID                uint       `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name              string     `json:"name"`
    Surname           string     `json:"surname"`
    Cellphone         int        `json:"cellphone"`
    AuxiliarCellphone int        `json:"auxiliarCellphone"`
    Email             string     `json:"email"`
    Patients          []*Patient `json:"patients" gorm:"many2many:professional_patient"`
}
```

and the get functions are

```
func GetAllPatients(c *gin.Context) {
    var patients []models.Patient

    internal.DB.Preload("Professionals").Find(&patients)

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": patients})
}
```

and

```
func GetAllProfessionals(c *gin.Context) {
    var professionals []models.Professional

    internal.DB.Preload("Patients").Find(&professionals)

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": professionals})
}
```

when i make a get request in postman for the professionals, the patients field return an empty array (which i think is fine because they don't have any patient loaded yet)

but in the case of the patients they return a "null" in the professionals field and the log in vscode says:

`[2020-07-10 02:04:52]  can't preload field Professionals for models.Patient`

What can I do here?

Comment: "professional_patient" this table got generated ?

Comment: @SauravKumarSingh yes, the table is getting created correctly

and inside it has two keys:
professional_id
patient_id